# android ksoap2 - faultcode: 'S:Client' faultstring: 'Cannot find dispatch method

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've looked for many threads but none of them helped to solve this.

**shortcut:**  How should look like the following urls, when we want to access localhost web service from emulator:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/";
private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/SerwerWS?wsdl";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/hello";
private static String methodName = "hello";
```

**The problem:**

There is web service based on SOAP hosted on local pc. It is tested and accessible locally. Eg.: urls

```
http://localhost:8080/SerwerWS/SerwerWS?Tester
http://localhost:8080/SerwerWS/SerwerWS?wsdl
```

The WSDL definitions node contain:

```
targetNamespace="http://serwer.me.org/"
name="SerwerWS"
namespace="http://serwer.me.org/"
schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/SerwerWS/SerwerWS?xsd=1"
```

There are two methods where wsdl defines:

```
<portType name="SerwerWS">
<operation name="hello">
<input wsam:Action="http://serwer.me.org/SerwerWS/helloRequest" message="tns:hello"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://serwer.me.org/SerwerWS/helloResponse" message="tns:helloResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="getImage">
<input wsam:Action="http://serwer.me.org/SerwerWS/getImageRequest" message="tns:getImage"/>
<output wsam:Action="http://serwer.me.org/SerwerWS/getImageResponse" message="tns:getImageResponse"/>
</operation>
</portType>
```

When I runproject from ide it depoly web with url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Serwer/
```

It works when I access this from browser. 
To access it from Android there's used **ksoap2 library**. Accessing with  Genymotion emulator(localhost set to 10.0.3.2) as:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/";
private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/SerwerWS?wsdl";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/hello";
private static String methodName = "hello";
```

**call**

```
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                    .getResponse();
```

**response**

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Client' faultstring: 'Cannot find dispatch method for {http://10.0.3.2:8080/SerwerWS/}hello' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

To verify if genymotion is ok I've connected sample app with some free web  SOAP service with no issues. 
Even `http://localhost:8080/Serwer/` in geny `http://10.0.3.2:8080/Serwer/` is ok.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the OutputSoapObject?

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, method);
```

....

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```